# Why is a Proxy allowed to skip looking up properties in the prototype?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

According to the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver), *obj*.[[Get]] is resolved as follows:

1. First check whether an object has the key (GetOwnProperty)
2. If it does not, defer to [[Get]] of *obj*’s prototype.
3. […] (other steps omitted)

However, the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver) for *proxy*.[[Get]] performs the following:

6. […] (some steps omitted)
7. If the trap is for [[Get]] is missing, defer to *target*.[[Get]].

This leads to the following inconsistency when combined with getPrototypeOf: an object can be considered an instance of some type T, but have no methods of that type.

Example as follows:

```js
var o = {};
var p = new Proxy(o, { 
  getPrototypeOf(target) { return Array.prototype;} 
});

console.log(p instanceof Array) //true
console.log(p.push) //undefined
```

Technically this behavior can be fixed by writing a [[Get]] handler, but this will likely push the performance down to unusable levels*.

* Experimenting on a module system inspired by ruby's. This suggests that every module function call will run through 1 or more proxy.[[Get]]s, which cuts performance to at least 1/10.  Very crude benchmarks suggest 130× (instantiation) - 500× (function call) performance penalty for my own implementation.

Comment: And what's your question? If you want a discussion of this behavior you might rather write to https://esdiscuss.org .

Comment: My question was if that behavior was inconsistent. I was not aware that this was not the appropriate place to discuss this.

Comment: Also note that at least for this example, your object will also fail `Array.isArray(p)`. This could be a slight inconsistency, it's true, but I agree ESDiscuss might be a better place to ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's inconsistent per se: you've just discovered one of many "invariants" that proxies allow you to violate. (Scare quotes because it's not one of the [invariants](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-invariants-of-the-essential-internal-methods) in the spec.)

If you want [[Get]]'s behavior to match that implied by [[GetOwnPrototype]], you can as you say write your own handler, or just not put a handler on [[GetOwnPrototype]].

Comment: Thanks. The spec seems to be surprisingly sparse in the department of invariants.